# Develop and Test a Facebook application

Tags: facebook, testing

Typically I develop my websites on trunk, then merge changes to a testing branch where they are put on a 'beta' website, and then finally they are merged onto a live branch and put onto the live website.

With a Facebook application things are a bit tricky. As you can't view a Facebook application through a normal web browser (it has to go through the Facebook servers) you can't easily give each developer their own version of the website to work with and test.

I have not come across anything about the best way to develop and test a Facebook application while continuing to have a stable live website that users can use. My question is this, what is the best practice for organising the development and testing of a Facebook application?

Comment: Can't each developer setup their own Facebook app, but just keep it private? That's what I did with a friend...

Comment: Are you talking about Facebook connect ? because a facebook normal canvas app is separated from normal web site and you can make it live once you have done all the development.

Comment: Hi Arfeen: Ya am talking about fb connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

What we have is 2 versions of our app, that is two applications defined in facebook.

We have the regular version that runs on deploy, and we have the `myapp-test` version. 
this version runs on the domain `myapptest.com` (or you can use `myapp.local`).

In your `HOSTS` file (`%winder%\system32\drivers\etc`) define this url and redirect it to your own server on localhost (`127.0.0.1`).

Now, all you need is a config file on each machine that is not updated via source-control. 
The localhost (development) version uses the `app_id` for the `myapp-test`, and relevant settings. 
The deploy uses the other settings.

Then when you deploy you just need to upload your code.